# $|f′(x)| \leq c|f(x)|$ for all $x \in (0,1)$ and $f(0)=0$. Show that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f : [0,1] → \mathbb R$ be a real-valued continuous function which is differentiable on $(0,1)$ and satisfies $f(0) = 0$. Suppose there exists a constant $c ∈ (0, 1)$ such that$|f′(x)| \leq c|f(x)|$ for all $x \in (0,1)$ and $f(0)=0$. Show that $f(x) = 0$ for all $x \in [0,1]$.

My proof - Given $f(0)=0$, let $x \in (0,1),$ then by MVT, we have for some $x_0 \in (0,x)$ s.t. $$|f(x)/x| = f'(x_0)$$ and we have $0<x_0<x$. Similarly, applying MVT again, for some $x_1$ such that $0<x_1<x_0<1$ we have
$$|f(x)|= c|f(x_0)|x_0<c|f(x_0)|<c|f'(x1)|x_1 $$
$$|f(x)|< c^2|f(x_1)|x_1<c^2|f(x_1)|.$$

Continuing this way we have

$$|f(x)|<c^n|f(x_n)|$$
and as $n \rightarrow \infty $, $|f(x)|=0$.

Is this argument correct?

Comment: oh sorry it is given f(0)=0, is it correct then?

Comment: The title is false.  Take $f(x)=2$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no need to iterate the MVT.

For $x\in (0,1]$ we have

$$|f(x)|\le \left |\frac{f(x)}{x}\right| \overset{MVT}{=} |f'(m_x)|<c |f(m_x)|\le c \max_{x\in [0,1]} |f(x)|$$

If the maximum on the RHS is attained at $0$, then we're done. Otherwise, it is  attained at some point $x_1\in (0,1]$, and we therefore have  $|f(x_1)| \le c |f(x_1)|$, which implies $|f(x_1)|=0$.

Comment: While yours is a much cleaner argument, is my solution correct? Thanks anyway

Comment: Not yet, but  your key  idea is correct: for  $x \in (0,1)$, $|f(x)| \le c |f(y)|x\le  c |f(y)|$, where $y \in (0,x)$. Iterating this we have $|f(x)|\le c^n |f(x_n)|\le c^n \to 0$, where $x>x_1 >x_2 \dots$ (we do not claim the sequence tends to $0$. It is not necessary).

Comment: yes, quite right, I have not assumed that $x_n \downarrow 0$, its not required, I would have used $e>0$ and $c^n<e,$ for some n and f is bounded, however, why would it be not necessary, that $x^n\downarrow 0$, it seems so it would.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to observe is this: Suppose not. Let $y \in (0,1)$ be such that $f(y) \not = 0$. Then by MVT there is an $x \in (0,y)$ s.t. $|f'(x)| = \frac{|f(y)|}{y} > 0$. Thus $|f'(x)|$ is strictly positive, and by the continuity of $f$ on $(0,1)$, it follows that $f(x)$ is bounded. Thus $|\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}|$ is strictly greater than 0 (or is $\infty$). So take $c =|\frac{f'(x)}{2f(x)}|$ if $f(x)$ satisfies $f(x) \not = 0$ and take $c=1$ if $f(x)$ satisfies $f(x)=0$, it will follow that $f'(x) > cf(x)$ for such $x$, which contradicts the assumption.

Comment: would you mind looking into my solution again

Comment: I still cannot follow. I am not seeing what $c$ is.

Comment: that is given in the question

Comment: How do you know though that $f(x_n)$ isn't going to infinity.

Comment: f is continuous on a closed and bounded interval

Comment: I suppose this would work. This seems to be a very convoluted way of doing this though. The way you wrote your proof is also difficult to follow.

Comment: ...and there are typos...a missing absolute value sign here, a lack of a subscript there....

Answer (score 0):

The MVT yields an $x_0$, such that $|f(x)/x|=|f^{\prime}(x_0)|$. It is not quite clear to me how your construction continues at the "similarly" part. You would need to elaborate on how you construct these constants.

Alternatively, note that $|f^{\prime}(x)|\le c|f(x)|$ for *all* $c\in(0,1)$ implies that $|f^{\prime}(x)|=0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$ (take a sequence $(c_n)_n$ in $(0,1)$ such that $c_n\rightarrow0$ and take limits in the inequality). Thus $f$ is constant on $[0,1]$ and you may conclude from $f(0)=0$ that $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: would you mind looking at my solution again?

Comment: "Suppose there exists a constant c ∈ (0, 1) such that|f'(x)|≤c|f(x)| for all c,x∈(0,1)". This makes no sense. Is c fixed or variable?

Comment: that is part of the question

Comment: The task as stated in the title makes sense. The phrasing of the hypotheses in the question does not. There is little reason to look at a proof that doesn't even state the hypotheses correctly and I think that you would benefit from inspecting them first.

Answer (score 0):

If $|f'(x)| \leq c|f(x)|$ for all $c \in (0,1)$, then $|f'(x)| = 0$, implying $f$ is constant. Since $f(0) = 0$, $f$ is zero everywhere.

Comment: if you could prove that it would be very helpful

Comment: please see the edit